# Modify php script to populate SQL Server 2012

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have this php script that parses data from a regular url in the form of "http://example.com/board.php?username=John&score=15&session=976837465", places that in a simple MySQL db, then sorts the score to form a top 10.

Can someone help me with the code to do **the same** for a SQL Server 2012 db? Please assume that the db has already been created.

Note : I know the method above is insecure and not recommended, but at present it is the only way I am able to pass data over - trust me on this.

Please find the full php code below.

Thanks in advance,
John

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost'; // Database Host Name - usually 'localhost'
$dbname = 'mydb'; // Database Name
$dbuser = 'myusername'; // Database User Name
$dbpass = 'mypassword'; // Database User Password

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);

$game = 'My Game'; // The Name of your game
{
$name = urldecode(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']));
$score = intval(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score']));
$gamesession = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['session']);
global $tlb;
if (!empty($game) && !empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($gamesession)) {
$query    = "INSERT INTO game_leaderboard (game, name, score, session) 
             VALUES('$game', '$name', '$score', '$gamesession')";
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);
} 
}
?>

<html>
        <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One'
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body> 
<div role="main">
<header>
    <h2 class="toptitle">My Game</h2>
</header>

<?php
$lboard = "SELECT * FROM game_leaderboard WHERE game = '$game' ORDER BY score DESC     LIMIT 10";
$leaderboard = mysql_query($lboard) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$lboard);
?>
<table class="th">
<thead style="background:#f7f7f7;">
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 18px; width:30%;">Name</td>
<td style="font-size: 18px; width:70%;">Score</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="background:#ffffff;border:1px solid #bfbfbf;">
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < mysql_numrows($leaderboard)) { ?>

<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;">
    <td><?php echo ucwords(mysql_result($leaderboard,$i,"name")); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo mysql_result($leaderboard,$i,"score"); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
</tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has made it easy to access data from any database, you can follow this guide i found here for ms sql servers http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html